# Is it possible to enable Apache Proxy Cache on the error status responses (403 or 404) too?

Tags: angular, apache, caching, proxy, server-side-rendering

We are using Apache Web Server (HTTPD) as a proxy for the Angular Universal (SSR) app. The cache works fine while the response status code of Angular App is 200. We confirm that cache works properly through the `X-Cache: HIT from <url>` header. But we also want Apache to cache responses with the status codes like 403 or 404. This does not seem to happen because we are getting the `X-Cache: MISS from <url>` header inside the response. Is it possible to configure Apache Cache (or Proxy) to ignore the error status codes and therefore cache such responses? (please note that we need the error response status code to remain in the response... the workaround by swapping the 403/404 status code with 200 inside the apache cache/proxy config does not work for us because we do need error response code to remain for the search engines or robots).

Answer (score 0):

So after researching this question and reading carefully through the Apache documentation, I found out a pretty simple answer on this page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html in the "**What Can be Cached?**
" section. Turns out that if you want to cache non success responses (e.g. 403 or 404), the actual application (proxy destination) which is our case is Angular SSR has to provide a Cache-Control or Expires response headers. So we did this simply with the following method, e.g.:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.scss']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {
  private response: Response;
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) response: any
  ) {
    this.response = response;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.response) {
      this.response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=86400');
      this.response.status(404);
    }
  }

}
```

As you may understood already, Angular SSR does not provide any cache response headers by default. That's why you need to set them explicitly in your app.

Hope that helps someone who had similar issue.